# Javascript search replace string from array

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new in javascript. I want to replace string value from array if array key value match with string value
Here is my following code:

```
var arr= [];
arr[11] = 'XYZ';
arr[12] = 'ABC';

var string = "11-12";
```

My Output will be :

```
var str ="XYZ-ABC";
```

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: Will the values in string be unique, will the array value never contain a array index?

Comment: Values in the string is unique

Comment: does the string contain only spaces and dashes as seperator? Then you could try to split it up

Comment: can you please explain a little better what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: String seperator is only dashes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method with a callback.

```js
var arr = [];
arr[11] = 'XYZ';
arr[12] = 'ABC';

var string = "11 - 12";

// match all digits in string and replace it with 
// corresponding value in `arr`
var res = string.replace(/\d+/g, function(m) {
  return arr[m];
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regx.test() to get the Boolean value to check if it is character or not .

```
var arr = [];
arr[11] = 'XYZ';
arr[12] = 'ABC';

if(/[a-zA-Z\s]+/.test(arr[11])&&/[a-zA-Z\s]+/.test(arr[12])){
var str=arr[11]+ " " +arr[12];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need array methods (split map and join), neither regex nor jquery:

```
var str = string.split("-").map(elem => arr[elem]).join("-");
```